# How to change Oracle password from Datagrip?

Tags: oracle, change-password, datagrip

Datagrip is connected to an Oracle database, and when trying to run `password`, the following error is shown:

```
[42000][900] ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Is there a correct way to change one's database password from within Datagrip, or is another tool required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`password` is a SQL*Plus command that may not work in other tools.  But you should be able to use this SQL command instead:

```
alter user test_user identified by "new_password" replace "old_password";
```